# Windows Phone 8 w/ REST or SOAP

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-8

I didn't find any resources about this topic. Can you help me? My question is: Can I use REST or SOAP web services with wp 8 or it just supports WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get HttpClient on nuget see here + example: http://maxgershkovich.wordpress.com/2013/09/30/calling-webapi-service-from-windows-phone-8-using-httpclient/